# Meteor: collection find

Tags: mongodb, meteor

what is the best way to find collections in Meteor by ids?

I've tried this method:

```
UserCollection.findCollectionsByIds = function (ids) {
    var collections = UserCollection.find({user: Meteor.userId(), _id: { $in: [ids]}});
    return collections;
}
```

where:
    ids = ['asgdajksdqa', 'ashudkjhaskc'] //an array of Object id

Now if I'm going to make a query like:

```
firstId = isd.pop();
var collections = UserCollection.find({_id: firstId });
```

it work correctly, so really I didn't understand what is wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
UserCollection.find({user: Meteor.userId(), _id: { $in: [ids]}});
```

with

```
UserCollection.find({user: Meteor.userId(), _id: { $in: ids}});
```

Since `ids` is already an array `['asgdajksdqa', 'ashudkjhaskc']`, if you wrap it in `[...]`, you'll get `[['asgdajksdqa', 'ashudkjhaskc']]`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I have another question: you know how sort the colelctions? I've tried that: Snippet.findMySnippet = function (userId) {
    return Snippet.find({user: userId}, { sort: { _id : -1 }});
} But it doesn't works If I'm going to add a new ones. I have to create a filed with the cerationTime?